# Communicate with unix-domain socket through scripting

Tags: python, unix, unix-socket

I'm getting bus error when attempt to write to unix-socket from my client application, so I wanted to debug my connection and communicate through this socket by writing some basic script commands directly from command line bash/python for debugging my connection.

Seems like simple echoing operation is not supported on the socket, Perhaps there's a simple python package to communicate with the socket ?

Comment: Please add the code that creates and accesses the socket, and the things you tried from the command line and your results/errors. Thank you.

Comment: Try [`nc -U`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)